# How to give permissions to specific command?

Tags: command-line, permissions, sudo

I would like to run `fastboot` command without `sudo`. it's working if I put `sudo` in front of it, otherwise it wont.

like this:

```
$ sudo fastboot devices
2738006a    fastboot

$ fastboot devices
no permissions  fastboot
```

How do I solve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Using sudoers file

The correct way is to add a line into your `/etc/sudoers` file similar to:

```
username     ALL = NOPASSWD: /bin/path/to/fastboot
```

which means this specific 'username' is able to run `fastboot` command using `sudo` without providing any password as `anyone`.

Now when you run it using `sudo fastboot` it won't ask you for password and is a little bit faster to work with.

Then simply add a simple alias to your `.bashrc`:

```
alias fastboot='sudo fastboot'
```

---

#### Using SUID bit

I highly recommend the above solution over this one;

If your `fastboot` program is a binary file you can do as follow:

```
sudo chown root:$(id -gn) /path/to/fastboot
sudo chmod 4750 /path/to/fastboot
```

First we make sure that `root` is the owner of this file and also it belongs to your primary group, then we make it possible for the owner and group to run this file while adding the SUID bit (4) which means file will be run with the owner's rights (root).

Now it should work without sudo, however only root and you are able to run it.

Answer (score 0):

Did you see this link? With change in /etc/sudoers file you can easily do that.

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/215412/allow-certain-guests-to-execute-certain-commands